# Unix upper case to lower case

Tags: linux, unix, vi

I have two lines in vi say:

A B C D E F
a B c D 4 F
5 a C d E f

I have to replace upper case letters to 1 and lower case letters to 2.
i want to do this for the whole file. lets say there are more than 10 lines.

Help please

Comment: That's more like three lines...

Comment: Your title says Unix, your question says vi. Which one is it? Do you look for a shell script, or a vi shortcut/plugin/whatever?

Comment: a normal single vi command is good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use regular expressions.

`:%s/[a-z]/1/g`

`:%s/[A-Z]/2/g`

Comment: You can join multiple substitution commands using a ``|``. In this case, ``:%s/[a-z]/1/g|%s/[A-Z]/2/g``

Answer (score 3):

in vim, `\u` matches uppercase character, `\l` matches lower case character. so you can do followings to achieve your goal:

```
:%s/\u/1/g|%s/\l/2/g
```

you can use `[a-z] or [A-Z]` too, but "**Using the atom is faster than the [ ] form.**"

Answer (score 0):

Using vi:

```
:%s/[A-Z]/1/g
:%s/[a-z]/2/g
```